# How can I handle ChirpSDK events with series of promises in WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming, webassembly, chirp

I have designed a payload dispatch which is generating a chirp but on the receiver side how can I incorporate  `onReceiving`& `onReceived` events while decoding sound or chirp to my data in webpage

My Chirp Instantiation:

```
      var chirp = Chirp({
        key: CHIRP_APP_KEY,
        onReceiving: () => {
        this.setState({
          received: '...',
          disabled: true
        })
      },
        onReceived: data => {
          console.log('xyz')
          if (data.length > 0) {
            console.log(toAscii(data))
          } else {
            console.error('Decode failed')
          }
        }
      });
```

CHirp SDK invoke in wasm

```
        chirp.then(sdk => {
          console.log(sdk)
          sdk.start().then(() => {
          // sdk.onReceiving()
          })
        }).catch(console.error)
```

in this scenario how can I incorporate series of promises?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what are you trying to achieve?  Do you want to convert callbacks into promises?

Comment: @Dinu yes in a sequential way, but could not proceed with promise.all()

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in any function to the ChirpSDK when instantiating, which are called when data has started/finished being received. These functions could do anything you like, such as dispatch an event. See https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/wasm

You can find an example using the Chirp WebAssembly SDK with a frontend framework such as React in this blog post - https://blog.chirp.io/chirp-in-react/